# How to select each child of div and get nth number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pug

So i have really stupid problem. I am making the design for official game web-site. And he told me that there will be a lot of screenshots. I made a design, and everything is working really cool, but there is really a lot of them so i want to close them in Mobile version (px < 640px) via jQuery, and create the button to show them after that. I know that there are a lot of instructions in the Internet, but they are not comparing to my markup at all, and actually i want it to exactly the same structure as i think.
So what i want is to find nth-child number of each child of my images-block, and every block which nth-child number is more than 4 to .hide(). Thanks for helping!

```
      <div class="images-block">
        <div class="image-sq">
          <p>⇕ Expand</p>
        </div><div class="image-sq">
          <p>⇕ Expand</p>
        </div><div class="image-sq">
          <p>⇕ Expand</p>
        </div><div class="image-sq"> 
          <p>⇕ Expand</p>
        </div><div class="image-sq"> 
          <p>⇕ Expand</p>
        </div><div class="image-sq">
          <p>⇕ Expand </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `gt` selector.

```
$(".images-block .image-sq:gt(3)").hide();
```

https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

> Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

Comment: the gt selector? what he doing? select each image after third?

Comment: `gt` = "Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set." - Thats not what the OP is asking for I don't think? EDIT: looks like it was after all haha. +1 for reading between the lines ;-)

Comment: No, it is zero indexed. So that means every image after fourth

Comment: @RichardHamilton wait, i cant open them
' $('.button--show-more').click(function () {
    console.log('Hi!')
    $('images-block .image sq:gt(3)').css('dispay', 'inline-block');
  });' is not working

even show command is not working

Answer (score 1):

I advice to use css3 media query way. It makes your page responsive for example you have a class called "image-sq" yo can type a css in style tag or in separeted css file like this:

```
@media (max-width: 640px)
.image-sq{
display: none\\ or visibility:hidden
 }
```

but not that's all you can type it in a range for ex.:

```
@media (min-width: 32.5em) and (max-width: 38.688em)
.image-sq{
width: 300px;
}
```

it makes your page flexiable screen to an other screen

Comment: emm, but i want to do it with JS bc i want to open them after clicking, and don;t want to change the style via jQuery, that means that the only way to dothat is checkbox trick, but that take a lot of time and a lot of bugs can appear

Comment: You know better. Good luck